# show search results on menu item click in magento

Tags: search, magento

By default the search functionality is implemented this way. 
User enters some text in the input search box and on click of "search" button the search results come up.

But I want the search results to show up on click of a menu item "Search" in top menu bar instead of the default "Search button".

How can this be done. Please suggest. Thanx.

Comment: Search is currently performed by clicking the "Search" button, but you want users to enter text *then* hit the "Search" button to show results?  I'm not following..

Comment: No I want the users to click a menu item("Search") in menu bar at top and then get search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not tested!**  Put this somewhere in your theme's layout.

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
            <label>Search</label>
            <url>javascript:searchForm.form.submit()</url>
            <title>Click Here To Search</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Then when it is working remove the old button from the `catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml` template.

Comment: In the catalog/navigation/top.phtml file I put this "javascript:searchForm.form.submit()"as href of of one of the menu items but on entering search terms and clicking the menu item, it returns no search result but on clicking the default search button the results appear.

Comment: In your browser's javascript console enter `searchForm.form.submit()` and see what happens. It might give an error message explaining what is wrong.

Comment: Thanx. It worked:) I just had to reindex data in index management.